# sh shell script of working with for loop

Tags: shell, sh

I am using sh shell script to read the files of a folder and display on the screen:

```
for d in `ls -1 $IMAGE_DIR | egrep "jpg$"`
do
  pgm_file=$IMAGE_DIR/`echo $d | sed 's/jpg$/pgm/'`

  echo "file  $pgm_file";
done
```

the output result is reading line by line:

> file file1.jpg
>
> file file2.jpg
>
> file file3.jpg
>
> file file4.jpg

Because I am not familiar with this language, I would like to have the result that print first 2 results in the same row like this:

> file file1.jpg; file file2.jpg;
>
> file file3.jpg; file file4.jpg;

In other languages, I just put d++ but it does not work with this case.

Would this be doable? I will be happy if you would provide me sample code.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Note : echo has a '-n' option for not adding an end-of-line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the shell do more work for you:

```
end_of_line=""
for d in "$IMAGE_DIR"/*.jpg
do
  file=$( basename "$d" )
  printf "file %s; %s" "$file" "$end_of_line"
  if [[ -z "$end_of_line" ]]; then
    end_of_line=$'\n'
  else
    end_of_line=""
  fi

  pgm_file=${d%.jpg}.pgm
  # do something with "$pgm_file"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for d in "$IMAGE_DIR"/*jpg; do
  pgm_file=${d%jpg}pgm
  printf '%s;\n' "$d"
done |
  awk 'END { 
        if (ORS != RS)
          print RS
          }
       ORS = NR % n ? FS : RS
       ' n=2
```

Set n to whatever value you need.
If you're on *Solaris*, use *nawk* or */usr/xpg4/bin/awk*
(do not use */usr/bin/awk*).

Note also that I'm trying to use a standard shell syntax,
given your question is *sh* related (i.e. you didn't mention *bash* or *ksh*,
for example).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this inside the loop:

```
echo -n "something; "
[[ -n "$oddeven" ]] && oddeven= || { echo;oddeven=x;}
```

should do.

Three per line would be something like

```
[[ "$((n++%3))" = 0 ]] && echo
```

(with `n=1`) before entering the loop.

Comment: Hi, I dont get it, what if I add 3 files in a line?

Comment: That would be different, this one just toggles linefeed. I'll add the snippet for you...

Answer (score 0):

Why use a loop at all?  How about:

```
ls $IMAGE_DIR | egrep 'jpg$' |
   sed -e 's/$/;/' -e 's/^/file /' -e 's/jpg$/pgm/' |
   perl -pe '$. % 2 && chomp'
```

(The perl just deletes every other newline.  You may want to insert a space and add a trailing newline if the last line is an odd number.)